# Is there any way to pass selector parameter inside puppeteer page.$$eval and then bind to the map?

Tags: puppeteer, eval, array.prototype.map

I tried different ways like add it to unnamed function, but without success. Thank you.

```js
var selector = '.tile-hover-target';

const prods = await page.$$eval(resultsSelector, function (msgs) {
     return msgs.map(function (selector, msg) {
        return {
           link: msg.querySelector(selector).href.trim(),
        }
     }.bind(null, selector))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Puppeteer documentation, arguments need to be passed after the function. This works fine:

```js
var sel = '.product-card__main';
      const prods = await page.$$eval(resultsSelector, function (msgs, sel) {
           return msgs.map(function (selector, msg) {
               return {
                    link: msg.querySelector(selector).href.trim(),
                       }
                }.bind(null, sel))
           }, sel);
```